# Why tarfile.open and tarfile.extractall methods raise errors?

Tags: python, tarfile

I am learning Python and related modules. Here are my scripts.

```
import tarfile
from six.moves import urllib

data_path = "./datasets/housing/"
file = "housing.tgz"
data_path_file = data_path + file
tar_file = tarfile.open(data_path_file)
# tested following script, failed
tar_file = tarfile.open(data_path_file,'r')
# end test
tar_file.extractall(path=data_path_file)
```

I hope my scripts can unzip the tgz file and write into a new file. I always received following error messages:

```
raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

I checked the path and file name. No errors exist. Any correction and further help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is `data_path_file` the name of the archive or the file that you're trying to extract from the archive?

Comment: Have you tried to open the file with another tar archive program? Maybe it is corrupted.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for `data_file_path` to be the argument to both `tarfile.open()` and `tar_file.extractall()`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your question. Yes. data_path_file is the archived source file with path.

Comment: @mrzo, thanks for your comments. No. I did not try another file. But I did untar this file using Bash scripts.

Comment: The `path` argument to `extractall` should be a directory where all the files will be extracted to. `data_file_path` is a file, not a directory.

Comment: data_file_path gives the source name and path. tar_file is the object I tried to open and untar. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you gave the full traceback, so we could see which line the error is happening on. Try changing `data_path` to an absolute pathname instead of relative, the current directory might not be what you think it is.

Comment: I have tested it before I posted my question here. originally, I gave the absolute path. However, I got the same error message.